# Transpose 2 SQL rows to Columns without single record rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, case, transpose

I'm trying to design a query to transpose the following table in SQL:

```
|Name| |Type|
  A       X
  B       X
  C       Y
  D       Y
  E       Z
```

to output:

```
|X|  |Y|  |Z|
 A    C    E
 B    D  <Blank>
```

But all I end up getting with pivot or with max case statements is:

```
  |X|  |Y|  |Z|
   A   Null Null
   B   Null Null
  Null  C   Null
  Null  D   Null
  Null Null  E
```

is this possible? Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'X' THEN Name END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Y' THEN Name END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Z' THEN Name END)
FROM (
  SELECT Name, Type, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
FROM mytable) AS t
GROUP BY rn
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for. Solution worked perfectly.

Comment: @SQALEX101 Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you have duplicate [Name], [Type] records and only want to see one, you would use DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER.  Also this is the PIVOT version.

```
SELECT  [X], [Y], [Z] 
FROM    (
    SELECT  [Name], [Type], 
            DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER BY [Name]) Rn
    FROM    Table1) t 
PIVOT (
    MAX([Name])
    FOR [Type] IN ([X], [Y], [Z])) p
```